# Grub2: Please explain me what does this command do?

Tags: boot, grub2

I'm learning grub2.  The following code shows a menu entry to boot an ubuntu image.

---

> ```
> > menuentry "Ubuntu 12.04.2 ISO"  {
> >         set isofile="/home/<username>/Downloads/ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso"
> >         # or set isofile="/<username>/Downloads/ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-i386.iso"
> >         # if you use a single partition for your $HOME
> >         loopback loop (hd0,5)$isofile
> >         linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz.efi boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile noprompt noeject
> >         initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz }
> ```

---

Can somebody explain me what does the "boot=casper" and  "iso-scan/filename=$isofile" in the above code do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.**boot=casper**

From its [man-page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man7/casper.7.html)

> Casper  is  a  hook  for  initramfs-tools used to generate an initramfs
>          capable to boot live  systems  as  those  created  by  make-live.  This
>          includes  the  Debian-Live isos, netboot tarballs, and usb stick images
>          and Ubuntu live cds. At boot time it will look for a (read-only)  media
>          containing  a  "/casper"  directory  where  a root filesystems (often a
>          compressed squashfs) is stored. If found, it  will  create  a  writable
>          environment, using unionfs, for debian like systems to boot from.

2 .  For the second A very good information like with examples from [ubuntu grub community](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot/Examples) and [menuentry details](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot#Menuentry_Details).

Comment: @curious_kid you are welcome my friend.